# GetDirectories returns path\\dir

Tags: c#, directory

I am using `string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories("instances", "*")` to get all the directories.

But it returns the directories as followed:

`instances\\test01, instances\\test02`

Then i use the following function to download a file to that directory:

```
FileDownloader downloader = new FileDownloader(dirs[0] + "/server/server.jar", "blabla");
```

But the file appear in the root directory instead.
Any suggestions?

Comment: use [path combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx)

Comment: @Sayse beat me to it. `Path.Combine()` is definitely the best solution, as it's also platform-independent.

Comment: @Nolonar - its embedded in my mind, i've spent the past 20 working hours refactoring other people's code..

Comment: @Nolonar: Yes, Path.combine is a good solution! but, what do you mean by Platform independent? Ofcourse, .net works only with windows right? Or do i sound silly?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) ;)

Comment: @Nolonar: Silly of me..I did'n know that. Thank you.. Got to learn it really

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `dirs[0] + "/server/server.jar"`

use

`Path.Combine(dirs[0], "/server/server.jar")`

I'd imagine that the string appending could be treating `\t` as a tab

Comment: I download the jar file with the webclient but this webclient doesn't handle the double slashes in the path. And then the jar keeps downloading in the root directory

Comment: The double slashes will only be in the visual studio window

Comment: After like 3 days searching I found my mistake :P thanks @Sayse you helpt me a lot by mentioning the double slashes in visual studio. I didn't know that :P

But my mistake was very stupid :P I the class where I download the file I had a hardcoded path. `client.DownloadFileAsync(url, "server.jar");` instead of `client.DownloadFileAsync(url, dir);`

Thanks everybody for your help :)

Comment: @Ghost - No worries :) The majority of people look for a way to remove the double slashes before they find out ;)

Comment: @Ghost - Click on the little spy glass if you ever want to see the real path

Comment: ok thanks for the info :). I will never make that mistake again :P